# Statically link ld.so (ld.a?)

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm working on a very low resources embedded system using linux kernel as OS. There are any distro or POSIX/GNU toolchain, only a kernel loaded on memory and a custom init process.

So far I've been using statically linked binaries, but now I need shared objects too. In order to keep simplicity and save resources I need ld.so functionality statically linked inside every binary.

There exist any portable solution that allow me to statically link a shared object loader inside my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a statically linked `libdl.so`, i.e. some (hypothetical) `libdl.a` (which probably would require a shared library loaded `ld.so`)

But I think that you should consider some other way, e.g. using a small [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) which provides its own `libdl` etc... You probably could customize it (so having a musl `libc.so` tailored to your needs) to contain only the object files and API that are needed to you.

Comment: I just asked this question on the musl chat room and someone pointed out that the static binary already has bits of libc linked in, but not all of it. And chances are a loaded library will need the missing bits. I tried a static link with a dlopen with musl and got "dlopen failed: Dynamic loading not supported".

Comment: Solved using `musl`, but you must compile dynamically. `libc.so` contains all necessary symbols, so you should set it as dynamic linker in a `gcc.specs` file.